# Environnent variables in front-end

Tags: angularjs, http

I'm working on a project in Java and I use Spring and AngularJS in particular. When my page loading (ng-init) I execute a function that calls a $http query that retrieves the list of environment variables. Then always load the page, I call another $http request that needs the result of my first query.

The problem is that the second query begins to run before the first query is finished, so at this time the environnent variable is undefined. I have an asynchronous query problem.

Do you know a solution please ?

Thank you

Comment: use promises for async operations

Comment: can you show some of your code, as far as I understand you should be able to just call your second $http in the .then() block of your first $http

Comment: $q.all([firstHttpRequestPromise]).then(/* do the other http request*/)

Answer (score 0):

Use promises. Make your first function async and put the second function in the .then() of the first function.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [documentation for the `$q`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) service, which is the AngularJs (1.x) implementation of [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

You probably have something like this

```
$http.get('url1')
    .then(function (response1) {
        console.log(response1);
    });

$http.get('url2')
    .then(function (response2) {
        console.log(response2);
    });
```

Your code should look something like this

```
$http.get('url1')
    .then(function(response1) {
        console.log(response1);
        return $http.get('url2')
    })
    .then(function(response2) {
        console.log(response2);
    });
```

Anything outside of the chained `.then` call on the promise returned by `$http` is not guaranteed (and probably won't ever) run after the `$http` call returns.

If you do not use promises (or the less often used callbacks) to control the asynchronous flow of `HTTP` requests/responses then you will not be able to guarantee when these operations happen in relationship to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Here my code, Document is a service and loadDocument return a http request:

```
$http.get('/env').then(function(variables) {
     Document.loadDocument(variables).then(function (data) {
             // next code.....
     });
});
```

When loadDocument is executed, variables is undefined. I don't understand very well the promises utilisation...